# 2L vs 2 in java expression

Tags: java

```
sum=(sum+2L*(A.length-count1[i])*count1[i])%1000000007;
sum=(sum+2*(A.length-count1[i])*count1[i])%1000000007;
```

whats the difference between these two statements? 
How is it related to overflow ?

count1 => integer type array
sum =>long type.

First statement gets my code submitted but second statement causes overflow in some case .
Won't java type cast 2 in code automatically how does 2L make it different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Won't java type cast 2 in code automatically?

No, Java won't cast 2 in code automatically to `long`.  Due to the precedence of operators, Java will perform the multiplication before the addition.  That means that `2`, an `int`, will be multiplied by `(A.length-count1[i])`, an `int`, and `count1[i]`, an `int`, resulting in an `int`.  Only when it's added to `sum`, a `long`, will that product be promoted to `long`.

> How does 2L make it different?

When you place `2L` in code, that is a `long` literal, so the multiplications promote the other `int`s to `long` before multiplication, making your calculations correct by preventing overflow.

The basic rules here to know here are:

- Java has operator precedence.  Here, for math, this follows math rules: *, /, % before +, -, and ()s before anything else.
- Java will promote to at least `int` via binary numeric promotion.  If either of the datatypes are "higher up" than the other, then the other value is promoted to that type before the operator calculates the result.
- But Java will not promote the types based on any overflow occurring.  You as the developer must anticipate possible overflow and type your variables and values accordingly, e.g. use `2L` here.

Comment: *"so the multiplications promote the other `int`s to `long` before multiplication"* No, the `(A.length-count1[i])` subtraction is still calculated using `int` math, and can cause overflow if `count1[i]` is a huge negative value. Only the *result* of the subtraction is widened to `long` before multiplication with the long `2L` literal.

Comment: @Andreas You're right.  It's important to note that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @rgettman already said it's also important to know that most expressions of the same precedence are evaluated from the left to the right.

The following code fragment tries to illustrate the whole story:

```
    long sum = 0;
    int largeInt = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    long someLong = 1L; // could be 1 as well

    assertNotEquals(2L * largeInt, 2 * largeInt);

    assertNotEquals(sum + 2L * largeInt * someLong, sum + 2 * largeInt * someLong);
    assertEquals(   sum + someLong * 2L * largeInt, sum + someLong * 2 * largeInt); // same as before, just in different order
```

All these assertions will succeed because of precedence and left-to-right evaluation.